# Installing Windows server 2008 on not VT system

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a Dell Inspiron 1440 laptop and it has no virtualization support, i want to install Windows Server 2008 on it using Virtual Box, i know that we can install Mac OS on not Virtualization supported system using some patch.
I also haired that Virtual box don't needs hardware virtualization, it will do that using software virtualization. how can i achieve that, any guidance would be very nice.
Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but if you are trying to install the 64-bit version, I doubt you will be able to do what you are wanting.

Comment: My system has 64 bit wondows7 and i am installing 64 bit widnows server using virtual box and hoping for the best because i have to replace my notebook.